# Mapping multiple columns to type in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to map select like this:

```
SELECT id, total, total_currency FROM sometable
```

id is VARCHAR, total is numeric, currency is char(3)

Into entity like this:

```
class MyEntity
{
     string Id { get; set; }
     Money total { get; set; }
}
```

Money of course has constructor with signature `(decimal amount, string currencyId)`. How do I achieve that in Dapper?

Comment: Why don't you use decimal for Money?

Comment: Because amount of money is meaningless if you don't know the currency.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use multi-mapping if you have a parent/child entity relationship, re: `Money` is a class that is a child property of `MyEntity`:

```
// assumes connection has already been created

string sql = "SELECT id, total, total_currency FROM sometable";

IEnumerable<MyEntity> result = conn.Query<MyEntity, Money, MyEntity>(
    sql,
    (entity, money) => { entity.Money = money; return entity; },
    spliton: "total");
```

For a more detailed explanation, see: [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/)

If you need custom parameters for the `Money` class, then it is recommended you just use the generic method and project the dynamic result into your actual result. See: [Call custom constructor with Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994933/)