# Nested constructor calls from Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

What's the best way to do the following...

```
conn.Query<Foo>(@"SELECT 1, 2, 'ZEBRA'");
```

Say `Foo` has a constructor like so...

```
public Foo(Bar test, string zebra)
```

..And `Bar` has a constructor like this:

```
public Bar(int one, int two)
```

This doesn't work, what would be the best approach to achieve the desired result.

Comment: `Foo(int first, int second, string derp) : this(new Bar(first, second), derp){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try non-generic Query API (more details are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995135/229949):

```
conn.Query(@"SELECT 1 as one, 2 as two, 'ZEBRA' as zebra")
  .Select(_ => new Foo(new Bar(_.one, _.two), _.zebra);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to hydrate into your real models directly from Dapper if they have constructor requirements like that. Instead, hydrate into a private/internal class, and then instantiate and return the proper models.

```
internal class FooBarQueryModel 
{
    public string Zebra { get; set; }
    public int One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
}

conn.Query<FooBarQueryModel>(sql).Select(qm => new Foo(new Bar(qm.One, qm.Two), qm.Zebra));
```

Comment: would this have some advantage over the 'dynamic' row solution, maybe performance?

Comment: Anything would be faster than using `dynamic`, even normal reflection. You pay a heavy price for it.